# creating a .csv from a combination of strings and panas dfs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

my `.csv` with multiple blocks need to follow this format (1 block sample):

[image]

so trying to do it in pandas and then write to csv. The problem is those comments above each of the two sections(outside the dataframes).

Here is sample code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
h_comment = pd.DataFrame(['#(H) Header'], columns=['name'])

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': 'Donald Trump',
                    'state':'FL',
                    'value':'0'},
                   index=[0])


data_comment =  pd.DataFrame(['#(S) Schedule'], columns=['A'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,4),
columns=list('ABCD'))

to_csv1 = pd.concat([h_comment,df1])
to_csv2 = pd.concat([data_comment,df2])
```

the issue is that those "comments" are inside  my df columns, for example:

```
to_csv2
Out[116]: 
               A         B         C         D
0  #(S) Schedule       NaN       NaN       NaN
0       0.521739  0.622079  0.322372  0.687531
1       0.991336  0.297848  0.635697  0.025620
2       0.068900  0.898806  0.562971  0.567817
```

the solution to first create a `.csv` with comments and append `dfs` to it is not great since there are many blocks like the above impacting the performance, so i'd rather write to csv at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image you shared looks more like an Excel spreadsheet rather than a [*csv*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file.

To make a csv that matches the shape you described, one option is to use [`open`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/functions.html#open) with [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) :

```
N = 2 # number of empty lines between both dfs

with open("output.csv", mode="w", newline="") as file:
    file.write("#(H) Header\n")
    df1.to_csv(file, index=False)
    file.write("\n"*N)
    file.write('#(S) Schedule\n')
    df2.to_csv(file, index=False)
```

Output (*.csv in Excel*) :

[image]

If needed, you can make with [`ExcelWriter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) a spreadsheet that can hande sheet/cell formatting :

```
with pd.ExcelWriter("output.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter") as writer:
    worksheet = writer.book.add_worksheet()
    
    header_format = writer.book.add_format({"border": None})
    title_format = writer.book.add_format({"bold": True,
                                           "italic": True,
                                           "font_size": 11})

    worksheet.write(0, 0, "#(H) Header", title_format)
    df1.to_excel(writer, index=False, startrow=1)
     
    worksheet.write(len(df1)+2, 0, "")
    worksheet.write(len(df1)+3, 0, "")
    
    worksheet.write(len(df1)+4, 0, "#(S) Schedule", title_format)
    df2.to_excel(writer, index=False, startrow=len(df1)+5)
    
    for col_num, value in enumerate(df2.columns):
        worksheet.write(len(df1)+5, col_num, value, header_format)
    
    for col_num, value in enumerate(df1.columns):
        worksheet.write(1, col_num, value, header_format)
        
    worksheet.autofit()
```

Output (*.xlsx in Excel*) :

[image]

Comment: apologies, replaced the image